# IBM Watson WebSocket Connection failure. HTTP authentication failed; no valid credentials avaliable

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ibm-watson

I am working on a speech-to-text web app using the IBM Watson Speech to text API. The API is fetched on the click of a button. But whenever I click the button. I get the above-mentioned error. I Have stored my API key and URL in a .env file.
I tried a lot but keep on getting this error. Please Help me out as I am new to all this.

I got server.js from the Watson Github Repo

Server.js

```
'use strict';

/* eslint-env node, es6 */
const env = require('dotenv');
env.config();
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const AuthorizationV1 = require('watson-developer-cloud/authorization/v1');
const SpeechToTextV1 = require('watson-developer-cloud/speech-to-text/v1');
const TextToSpeechV1 = require('watson-developer-cloud/text-to-speech/v1');
const vcapServices = require('vcap_services');
const cors = require('cors');

// allows environment properties to be set in a file named .env

// on bluemix, enable rate-limiting and force https
if (process.env.VCAP_SERVICES) {
  // enable rate-limiting
  const RateLimit = require('express-rate-limit');
  app.enable('trust proxy'); // required to work properly behind Bluemix's reverse proxy

  const limiter = new RateLimit({
    windowMs: 15 * 60 * 1000, // 15 minutes
    max: 100, // limit each IP to 100 requests per windowMs
    delayMs: 0 // disable delaying - full speed until the max limit is reached
  });

  //  apply to /api/*
  app.use('/api/', limiter);

  // force https - microphone access requires https in Chrome and possibly other browsers
  // (*.mybluemix.net domains all have built-in https support)
  const secure = require('express-secure-only');
  app.use(secure());
}

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
app.use(cors())


// token endpoints
// **Warning**: these endpoints should probably be guarded with additional authentication & authorization for production use

// speech to text token endpoint
var sttAuthService = new AuthorizationV1(
  Object.assign(
    {
      iam_apikey: process.env.SPEECH_TO_TEXT_IAM_APIKEY, // if using an RC service
      url: process.env.SPEECH_TO_TEXT_URL ? process.env.SPEECH_TO_TEXT_URL  : SpeechToTextV1.URL
    },
    vcapServices.getCredentials('speech_to_text') // pulls credentials from environment in bluemix, otherwise returns {}
  )
);
app.use('/api/speech-to-text/token', function(req, res) {
  sttAuthService.getToken(function(err, token) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error retrieving token: ', err);
      res.status(500).send('Error retrieving token');
      return;
    }
    res.send(token);
  });
});


const port = process.env.PORT || process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 3002;
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('Example IBM Watson Speech JS SDK client app & token server live at http://localhost:%s/', port);
});

// Chrome requires https to access the user's microphone unless it's a localhost url so
// this sets up a basic server on port 3001 using an included self-signed certificate
// note: this is not suitable for production use
// however bluemix automatically adds https support at https://<myapp>.mybluemix.net
if (!process.env.VCAP_SERVICES) {
  const fs = require('fs');
  const https = require('https');
  const HTTPS_PORT = 3001;

  const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/keys/localhost.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/keys/localhost.cert')
  };
  https.createServer(options, app).listen(HTTPS_PORT, function() {
    console.log('Secure server live at https://localhost:%s/', HTTPS_PORT);
  });
}
```

App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import 'tachyons';
//import WatsonSpeech from 'ibm-watson';
var recognizeMic = require('watson-speech/speech-to-text/recognize-microphone');


class App extends Component {

onListenClick = () => {

  fetch('http://localhost:3002/api/speech-to-text/token')
  .then(function(response) {
      return response.text();
  }).then(function (token) {

    var stream = recognizeMic({
        token: token, // use `access_token` as the parameter name if using an RC service
        objectMode: true, // send objects instead of text
        extractResults: true, // convert {results: [{alternatives:[...]}], result_index: 0} to {alternatives: [...], index: 0}
        format: false // optional - performs basic formatting on the results such as capitals an periods
    });

    stream.on('data', function(data) {
      console.log('error 1')
      console.log(data);
    });
    stream.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log('error 2')
        console.log(err);
    });
    //document.querySelector('#stop').onclick = stream.stop.bind(stream);
  }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log('error 3')
      console.log(error);
  });
}


render() {


return(
   <div>
      <h2  className="tc"> Hello, and welcome to Watson Speech to text api</h2>
      <button onClick={this.onListenClick}>Listen to Microphone</button>
    </div>
  );
}
}

export default App
```

Comment: have you tried hardCoding the creds to see if they are valid? or if the file is being read? If they are still not working, are they the valid creds?

Comment: yes...I did try hardCoding the creds but it just shows the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Since the only code you show is fetching an authorisation token then I guess that that is what is throwing the authentication failure. I am not sure how old the code you are using is, but the mechanism you are using was used when the STT service credentials are userid / password. The mechanism became unreliable when IAM keys started to be used.

Your sample is still using watson-developer-cloud, but that has been superseded by ibm-watson. As migrating the code to ibm-watson will take a lot of rework, you can continue to use watson-developer-cloud.

If do you stick with watson-developer-cloud and you want to get hold of a token, with an IAM Key then use:

```
  AuthIAMV1 = require('ibm-cloud-sdk-core/iam-token-manager/v1'),

  ...

  tokenService = new AuthIAMV1.IamTokenManagerV1({iamApikey : apikey});

  ...

  tokenService.getToken((err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      ...
    } else {
      token = res;
      ...
    }
  });
```